# how do i convert to an Excel file to xml file by uploading it using Javascript and call AJAX method?

Tags: javascript

I gone through some articles in the internet but i couldn't find any way to convert excel file to xml format. But i have tried this code convert excel to json but i have stuck convert excel file to xml using javascript ,Below i have tried the code to convert excel to json. Can someone help me to convert to xml.

```
<body>
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
    <hr />
    <div id="dvExcel">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("body").on("click", "#upload", function () {
            //Reference the FileUpload element.
            var fileUpload = $("#fileUpload")[0];

            //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
            if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();

                    //For Browsers other than IE.
                    if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    } else {
                        //For IE Browser.
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var data = "";
                            var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                                data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                            }
                            ProcessExcel(data);
                        };
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
            }
        });
        function ProcessExcel(data) {
            debugger;
            //Read the Excel File data.
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });

            //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
            var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];

            //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
            var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
            console.log(excelRows);
            //http://localhost:59900/WebService1.asmx

            var UserDetailscs = {};
            UserDetailscs.id = 1;
            UserDetailscs.Name = "2000";
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetCity',
                data: "{marriedList:" + JSON.stringify(excelRows) + "}",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (r) {
                    alert("Data inserted succesfully");

                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });


        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```